# Hide Label element only if javascript is enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

### I have a view that displays a textbox as follows:

```
  $(function() {
        $('[name="CodeGuest"]').hide();
    });
```

---

```
  @Html.Label("CodeGuest")
```

i am used above code but does not hide the label.what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `@Html.Label("CodeGuest")`, It will render the below HTML

```
<label for="CodeGuest">CodeGuest</label>
```

So your jQuery selector should look for items with that specific `for` property value like this

```
$(function() {
    $('label[for="CodeGuest"]').hide();
});
```

I suggest you to use another [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413942%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of `Html.Label` helper method where you can specify the HTML attributes, thus define an `ID` element for the label.

```
 @Html.Label("CodeGuest", new { @id="codeGuest"})
```

This will give you the markup with `ID` element so that you can use that to hide your element.

```
<label id="codeGuest" for="CodeGuest">CodeGuest</label>
```

Now your javascript code can be

```
$(function() {
    $("#codeGuest").hide();
});
```

Always try to use **SPECIFIC** jQuery selectors ( ID's instead of classnames etc..) instead of generic. That is faster.